# Which c++ implementation is preferable, range based loop or count_if

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I read the question which implementation is preferable to perform a count of some vector items.

Is this better than

```
auto countif = [] (T t) { return t.countable(); };
const int count = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), countif);
return count ;
```

this

```
int count = 0;
for (  auto& t : v ) 
    if (t.countable()) count++;
```

The question has been voted down and thus been deleted.

Comment: If you only would use good names. Why do you name the lambda countif? It's countable, is_countable or do_count or something like that.

Comment: The names came from the OP,  not come from me. I kept them in order for him to recognize his question.

Comment: Thats not a valid reason to use bad names. You are the OP here.

Comment: why did you delete your answer? Maybe it wasnt perfect, but real measured results are always interesting. Btw you have 3 close votes due to opinion-based. You could rephrase the question to ask specifically about speed performance, which isnt opinion based at all (but "what is better?" definitely is). You will still get comments that this is something that you can easily measure yourself, however, I wouldnt care too much about downvotes and just undelete your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *almost always* use an *algorithm* like [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) if one is available.

The reason is that the compiler vendor can put optimizations in that are not portable if you were to put them in manually in your own loop. For example there are *intrinsic* functions that could be `CPU` specific that speed up even basic tasks like counting values in an array.

Unless you have a specific need to use non-portable optimizations then *algorithms* provided by the compiler in the standard library are likely to be faster in a portable way than something you are likely to write.